# Kendo ui listview with flip animation effect

Tags: listview, kendo-ui, flip

I have a set of product images that I have displayed using Kendo UI listview. When the user clicks on the image, I want the image to flip and display an editable form which the user can fill and submit.

I was able to successfully do this by using [this demo](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/fx/combined.html) for a single image and a form. However, when I try to do it for all the elements in the listView by using template elements, the transition only works for the first element in the list (even when I click on any other element). How can I make this work?